# Set match_parent size for content's LinearLayout in TabHost (Android)

Tags: android, tabs, size, android-tabhost

I can't understand, why LinearLayout with ID "map_tab" (first tab) not have a height "match_parent" in fact?
I have a XML-file with TabHost:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:background="#ffff"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost_main"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!--Вкладка №1 - карта-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/map_tab"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <!--Карта-->
                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/map_img"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
                    </ScrollView>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sector_advert_text"
                    android:background="#ddffaa"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            <!--Вкладка №2 - акции-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/stock_tab"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:text="2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!--Вкладка №3 - Маршрут -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/route_tab"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <Button
                    android:text="3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

[ScreenShot](http://fotoseif.ru/images/2015/03/clj28l2m4y9a8ojcta6s.jpg)

I already try to set height to "fill_parent". It's look like "wrap_content" always. If I set height of "map_tab" to 50dp, for example, it will not OK too! Second and third tabs have this problem too.
What me do to make tab's content height "match_parent"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem!
Just change:

```
<TabHost
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tabHost_main"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

on:

```
<TabHost
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tabHost_main"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Good luck! :)